# django does not show value form db

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I have problem. My template don't show my value from db. 
I think that I don't have defined model UserProduct in views.py in function product.

**wievs.py**

```
def index(request):
  context = {
      'products': Product.objects.order_by('category').filter(is_published=True)
  }
  return render(request, 'offers/products.html', context)


def userproduct(request):
   context = {
      'userproduct': UserProduct.objects.filter(user_id=request.user.id),
  }
   return render(request, 'offers/userproducts.html', context)


def product(request, product_id):
   product = get_object_or_404(Product, pk=product_id)

   context = {
      'product': product,
   }
   return render(request, 'offers/product.html', context)
```

**models.py**

```
class Product(models.Model):
  product_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
  category = models.CharField(max_length=50)
  weight = models.FloatField()
  description = models.TextField(blank=True)
  photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/%Y/%m/%d/')
  is_published  = models.BooleanField(default=True)
  list_date = models.DateField(default=datetime.now, blank=True)

  def __str__(self):
    return self.product_name

class UserProduct(models.Model):
  user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  product_name = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  price = models.FloatField()
  is_published  = models.BooleanField(default=True)
  list_date = models.DateField(default=datetime.now, blank=True)

  def __str__(self):
    return str(self.user.username) if self.user.username else ''
```

offers/product.html

```
<div class="p-4">
              <p class="lead">
                  {% if user.is_authenticated %} 
                <span class="mr-1">
                  <p>Price</p></span>
                  <p class="colores lead font-weight-bold">{{ product.price }} £</p> 
                  {% endif %}
                  <p >Description</p>
                  <p class="colores lead font-weight">{{ product.description }}</p> 
              <p class="colores lead font-weight-bold">Weight: {{ product.weight }}kg</p> </p>
              {% if user.is_authenticated %} 
              <form class="d-flex justify-content-left">
                <!-- Default input -->
                <input type="number" value="1" aria-label="Search" class="form-control" style="width: 100px">
                <button class="btn send-click btn-md my-0 p" type="submit">Add to cart
                  <i class="fas fa-shopping-cart ml-1"></i>
                </button>
              </form>
              {% endif %}
            </div>
```

Value product.price does not show.

The idea is that each user will have a different product price.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because your `Product` model has no `price` field; What you have is `userproduct_set` as a **reverse** foreign key relationship from the `UserProduct` model.

So you may have multiple `price` for *one* `Product` instance.

You can use the following code to show all the available prices for your product:

```
<div class="p-4">
  <p class="lead">
    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
      <span class="mr-1">
      <p>Price</p></span>

      {% for userproduct in product.userproduct_set.all %}

        <p class="colores lead font-weight-bold">{{ userproduct.price }} £</p>

      {% endfor %}

    {% endif %}
  <p>Description</p>
  <p class="colores lead font-weight">{{ product.description }}</p>
  <p class="colores lead font-weight-bold">Weight: {{ product.weight }}kg</p> </p>
  {% if user.is_authenticated %}
    <form class="d-flex justify-content-left">
      <!-- Default input -->
      <input type="number" value="1" aria-label="Search" class="form-control" style="width: 100px">
      <button class="btn send-click btn-md my-0 p" type="submit">Add to cart
        <i class="fas fa-shopping-cart ml-1"></i>
      </button>
    </form>
  {% endif %}
</div>
```

Read more about them in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward).

#### Edit

As you mentioned in the comments, you want to find out the `price` assigned to the current logged in user, if the user is logged in and show `weight` and `description` even if the user is not logged in. So you need:

```
def product(request, product_id):
    product = get_object_or_404(Product, pk=product_id)
    user_product = None
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        user_product = UserProduct.objects.filter(product_name_id=product_id, user=request.user)
        if user_product:
            user_product = user_product.first()

    context = {
      'product': product,
      'user_product': user_product,
    }
    return render(request, 'offers/product.html', context)
```

and your template as well:

```
<div class="p-4">
  <p class="lead">
    {% if user.is_authenticated and user_product %}
      <span class="mr-1">
      <p>Price</p></span>
      <p class="colores lead font-weight-bold">{{ user_product.price }} £</p>
    {% endif %}
  <p>Description</p>
  <p class="colores lead font-weight">{{ product.description }}</p>
  <p class="colores lead font-weight-bold">Weight: {{ product.weight }}kg</p> </p>
  {% if user.is_authenticated and user_product %}
    <form class="d-flex justify-content-left">
      <!-- Default input -->
      <input type="number" value="1" aria-label="Search" class="form-control" style="width: 100px">
      <button class="btn send-click btn-md my-0 p" type="submit">Add to cart
        <i class="fas fa-shopping-cart ml-1"></i>
      </button>
    </form>
  {% endif %}
</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this code also does not display the price, What should I do to display only one price assigned to the product and user?

Comment: It works, but shows only assigned username to product.
I would like it to show only the price of the currently logged in user.

Comment: By the way if you want to show the price _associated_ with the current **authenticated** user, it's better to send a `UserProduct` object to the template (send `UserProduct.objects.get(product_name_id=product_id, user=request.user)`).

Comment: @yellowhand did you use `{{ userproduct.price }}` to get the price?

Comment: I don't understand where I must change `UserProduct.objects.get(product_name_id=product_id, user=request.user)`

Comment: if I change in def userproduct, and set 
 `'userproduct': UserProduct.objects.get(product_name_id=product_id, user=request.user)` I have error name 'product_id' is not defined

Comment: Now works, thanks. Only single product page is to be used for displaying the description and weight for not logged in users.
Now it is impossible, do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203521/discussion-between-pedram-parsian-and-yellowhand).